# How to connect mysql db in another host using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I don't know how connect into one mysql db in different host(server) to show medicament list in another website... can you help me with this?

here is the connection I use in the same server, but in different server I can't connect. Can you explain me how to do it?

```
<?php 
$dbtype     = "mysql";
$dbhost         = "localhost";
$dbname     = "XXXX_medicament";
$dbuser     = "XXXX_medicament";
$dbpass     = "123456789";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->exec("set names utf8");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
?>
```

here are the errors:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'XXXX_medicament'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/peri/includes/config.med.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/peri/includes/config.med.php(7):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'XXXX_medicament', '123456789')
>    #1 /home/XXXX/public_html/peri/inicio.php(32): include('/home/XXXX/...') #2 /home/XXXX/public_html/peri/home.php(7):
>   include('/home/XXXX/...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/peri/includes/config.med.php on line 7

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I edit my question with the errors

Comment: Try writing the user and password manually,don't just copy paste.

Comment: @Mihai let me explain is different machine, in my case the db where the medicamnet is have this form:  `xy_` to connect to the db,  now in the another site that I need to show the list of all medicament have the next syntaxis:  `xxxxy_`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the other database allows external connections. If it does, you have to change the database host address to the address of the mysql server.

Example:

```
$dbhost = "mysql.host.com";
```

or for an IP address

```
$dbhost = "123.123.123.123";
```

Comment: Now that you have updated the question with the error, it shows that you have inserted a wrong username or password.

Comment: You can use a host name or IP address - PDO doesn't care.

Comment: that is because is a different host or server is not the same machine(pc), so the database I tried to call is not in the same mysql phpmyadmin..I think..

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has nothing to do with this, it is only a tool for editing MySQL databases. The real problem is that you have to use the external IP address, and also change the username and password which are used to connect to that specific database.

Comment: ok, I think I understand... I need to insert the ip of the server where is the medicament db BUT I need to put the username and password of the database of the site I need to show it

Comment: when I put the ip where is my medicament db show me this error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '190.86.xxx.xx' (111)'`

Comment: This means that the remote MySQL server denies external connections.

Answer (score 0):

Simple then. You've got the password for user `XXXX_medicament` wrong! The username has a different password on the remote machine.

Try logging into the control panel provided by your web host and look for an option to configure databases. In there, you should be able to change passwords for users.

Comment: well I simple copy & paste the connection I already use in my site where I save the medicament. In my site working nice but in different server can't

Comment: On the remote database, the user `XXXX_medicament` has a different password - they're two different machines. You will have set up a password for `XXXX_medicament` on the remote database when creating the username.